# Wordpress: Changing the 'Password Protected' page

Tags: wordpress

I downloaded the WordPress plugin 'Password Protected' for my WordPress site, which adds a password to my webpage so no one can access the material in there without logging in first. It works great and does exactly what I want it to do. My issue is that I need to customize it (change the WordPress logo and add some text). I found multiple guides on how to do this but none that could be applied in my case.

this guide:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection#Customize_the_Protected_Text

Tells me to edit the functions.php file. However, I cannot access it from the WordPress admin interface.

this guide:
https://www.binaryturf.com/website-design/business/how-to-edit-functions-php-in-wordpress/

Tell me that it should be available by Apperance -> Editor
but there's no 'Editor' under Apperance for me.

Does anyone how I can edit the login-page for Password Protect, or any other plugin I could use that allows me to change logo and text for the login page (for free)? Or how I can edit the functions.php file in WordPress admin?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first reference URL is irrelevant as you said your using a plugin.

Comment: Follow your plugins documentation and / or seek support from them if you don't understand PHP programming.